# Why use super() instead of __init__()?

Tags: python, class, multiple-inheritance, superclass

If we have class `A`, defined as follows,

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
```

why do most people use

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x)
        self.y = y
```

instead of

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        A.__init__(self, x)
        self.y = y
```

? I think `A.__init__(self, x)` is better then `super().__init__(x)` because it supports *multiple inheritance* (and I didn't find a way to do it with `super()`):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
class B:
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y
class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        A.__init__(self, x)
        B.__init__(self, y)
        self.z = z
```

When I try to use `super()` in the previous example, like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
class B:
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y
class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        super().__init__(self, x)
        super().__init__(self, y)
        self.z = z
```

class `C` doesn't have attribute `y` (try: `c = C(1, 2, 3)` and `print(c.y)` in next line).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `super` is **precisely for** multiple inheritance, so you don't have to go through explicitly calling the method on the all of the individual superclasses.

Answer (score 0):

I you use `super().__init__()`, Python will automatically call all constructors of your base classes on its own in the right order (in your second example first `A`, then `B`constructors).

This is one of the beauty of Python, it handles multiple inheritance nicely :).